# Reading a span tag's value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read the text value of a span tag that is inside a td tag in a table. I want to access only that span's value only but i fail, as each time the entire row's text is returned:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> The cell i want <span style="color:#0000FF;"> I want this!! </span> </td>
<td>Not this</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried using:

```
$("table tr span[style='color:#0000FF']:first");
```

Comment: *"I tried using"* And? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using:
>
> `$("table tr span[style='color:#0000FF']:first");`

That would actually work, if you made the selector **exactly** match the element (you're missing the `;` after the color value — either remove it from the element's `style` attribute, or add it to the selector). (And if you use `.text()` to get the text of the span.) [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/AYADokiW/1)

But it's *really* fragile. If there's any other way you can identify that span, use the other way. For instance, it's the first span within the `td`, so:

```
var text = $("table tr span:first").text();
```

...would work, if you can rely on that.

Note that in both cases, you'll get the text from the first row that contains a matching span; subsequent rows will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this to get the span text

```
$("table tr td:first span:first").text();
```

or

```
$("table tr td:eq(0) span:first").text();
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZagL4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("table tr:first td:first span:first").text();
```

or simply:

```
$("table").find("span:first").text();
```

or

```
$("table span:first").text();
```

or

```
 $("table span:eq(0)").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
$('table tr td:first span').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you working and useful solutions. Upon implementing them my problem was solved but my mistake was not taking into consideration the entire page where this span is.

On its own this was easy(with your help of course!) but when it is part of a huge page that contains other controls it is difficult.
So using the id attribute has made things simpler.